# How to write a regex when using Boost to split a sentence

Tags: c++, boost, split

I want to use boost::algorithm::split_regex to split a sentence. But my delimiter is various and a whole. My split strategy is not is-any-one.

For example, `"i || love || you ||" -> i love you`
So the delimiter is `||`.

For example, `"***i***love***you***" -> i love you`
So the delimiter is `***`.

```
vector<string> tokens;
boost::algorithm::split_regex(tokens, sentence, boost::regex("XXX"));
```

I tried many regex for many times, but failed.
How to write an adaptive regex to achieve my goal?

Comment: You don't need regex to do this. Split by string instead.

Comment: Have I understood you right: you can't name finite list of possible delimeters in compile time?

Comment: I mean that there exists different delimiters for different sentences. I think boost is a faster way than standard c++.